# Different vendor file for production and development

Tags: elixir, brunch, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I'm using Phoenix 0.14.0 and I'm planning to use reactjs to create the user interface.

The way I'm doing this is just putting the react.min.js in the `web/static/vendor` folder.
The thing is, I want that in development the non-minified version of react be used instead, since it has the debugging code.

When I use the `react.min.js` the final size of the minified app.js is ~150K, and if I use `react.js` the final size is 550K, which I don't think is a negligible difference.

Is there a way I can use a different static file for production and for development in phoenix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either put the regular `react.js` in your project and let a plugin like [uglify-js-brunch](https://github.com/brunch/uglify-js-brunch) minify it for you on production builds, or you can put both files there and use [`overrides`](https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/master/docs/config.md#overrides) in your brunch config to include/exclude what you want depending on your environment. The latter might look something like this:

```
conventions:
  ignored: [
    /[\\/]_/,
    'web/static/vendor/react.min.js'
  ]
overrides:
  production:
    conventions:
      ignored: [
        /[\\/]_/,
        'web/static/vendor/react.js'
      ]
```

Comment: The second alternative works best for me, because "uglifying" react.js will still keep a lot of debug code, and whence it'll still be quite bigger than the version minified upstream.
Now I just have to figure it out how to make the phoenix "building tasks" use the right brunch conventions, when appropriate.